# iOS MFMailComposeViewController not attaching file

Tags: ios, swift, mfmailcomposeviewcontroller

Summary:

I am using the below snippet for sending an email from my app to an email address.
Below implementation works fine in case of configuration as below :

iOS Device  : Any

iOS Version : Below 12

However in case of iOS 12 and iPhone XR, I am not able to see attached file in mail. 
This is reproducible only on iPhone XR with iOS 12+. In case of other devices having iOS 12 the issue is not reproducible.

```
func sendMail(filePath:String){

let toRecipients = user@domain.com
let subject = “Email Subject”

let formatter = DateFormatter()
formatter.dateFormat="dMMMyyyy";
let dateString = formatter.string(from: Date())

let userName :String = “ABC”
var bodyText1: String?
var bodyTextLocation: String?

bodyText1 = "<html><body><br> " + “Date:” + dateString
bodyText1 = bodyText1! + "<br><br>------------------------------<br>"
        + “Contact us for additional help” + "</body></html>"

let body = "<html><body><br><br><br><br><br>" + UIDevice.current.model + "<br> " +  "</body></html>"
var bodyText2 :  String?
bodyText2 = body + bodyText1!

let mail = configuredMailComposeViewController(recipients: toRecipients, subject: subject, body: bodyText2!, isHtml: true, images: nil)

if let fileData = try? Data(contentsOf: URL(fileURLWithPath: filePath))
{
  print("File data loaded.")
  let logFileName = (filePath as NSString).lastPathComponent
  mail.addAttachmentData(fileData, mimeType: "text/plain", fileName: logFileName)
}
  presentMailComposeViewController(mailComposeVC: mail)
}


func presentMailComposeViewController(mailComposeVC : MFMailComposeViewController) {

if MFMailComposeViewController.canSendMail(){
  self.rootVC.present(mailComposeVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
 }else{
  //Error
 }
}
```

Steps to Reproduce:

Use iOS 12+ and iPhone XR
Use above code snippet

Expected Results:

File should get attached in email body.

Actual Results:

File is not getting attached in email body.
Note : This gets reproduced randomly.

Version/Build:

iOS 12+

Configuration used:

iPhone XR
iOS 12+

Comment: Add breakpoint and check if you are getting fileData. Also check filePath.

Comment: do you see the "File data loaded." line in your Xcode console log?